# Connecting to Ubuntu VM on virtualbox through putty and accessing Internet

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I want to run Ubuntu on VirtualBox. I have downloaded ready VM online. Also tried running the VM. Now I want Internet connection on this machine, and also want to connect to Ubuntu 32 bit Guest OS from my host (Windows 7 32 bit). How can I configured this. I tried both NAT and bridged. In both cases, it says  "Cable unplugged" I get following:

[image]

I also tried keeping two adapters as suggested by [this](https://www.ulyaoth.net/resources/tutorial-ssh-into-a-virtualbox-linux-guest-from-your-host.35/) article.

- Adapter 1 : Bridged Adapter
- Adapter 2 : Virtual Box Host Only Adapter

But it was still showing "Cable unplugged". Also on doing `ifconfig` it does not show IP address:

[image]

Whats wrong going on here? What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remember to click the "Cable Connected" in Virtualbox?

[image: Virtualbox network settings]

Comment: damn man this worked...such a creepy checkbox. They should have by default checked it. Not I have **1.**NAT adapter  **2.**Host-only Adapter. Now I am able to access Internet. However connecting to it using putty gives "Network Error: Connection Refused"

Comment: I agree!

On the NAT adaptor you need to add a port forward. Add this: 
`ssh | TCP | 22 | 127.0.0.1 | 2222 | <empty> | 22` - 
Then you should be able to ssh to your localhost port 2222. Sorry for the poor formatting.

Comment: aargh I am not able to `ssh localhost 22` on my VM. Tried `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`...my company proxy blocking stuff from resolving mirror :(  Now just guessing if I can download openssh-server and all its dependecies offline and mail it and download it on VM (copy-paste/drag drop also not working between host and guest). I have another Ubuntu machine which I may use to download openssh-server and packages. But is it possible to zip them, mail them and then install from downloaded mail?

Comment: copied all openssh related deb files from the another Ubuntu machine to V and ran `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`...realized my Ubuntu machine was of 64 bit and VM is 32 bit :'(  Is there any way that I can download all deb packages  from some website?

Comment: Can't you use a proxy server or install from a media (add the .iso file as a CD/DVD to your VM)?
That or just download the 32 bit deb packages.

Comment: ok thats done. I am able to connect to VM using putty. But one more issue. I have one server running on VM which I access from inside VM in browser at url `http://localhost:50070`. Now I created a port forwarding rule for this too as follows: `tcp|127.0.0.0|50070|<vm's-ip>|50070`. But when I try accessing `http://127.0.0.1:50070` from host's browser, it says "Page Not Found". Is it like, I can only configure port forwarding for TCP not HTTP?

Comment: HTTP is TCP traffic so there is no reason it shouldn't work just like your SSH works.

Comment: Sure? It is really not working. Have done this before? Or should I be configuring second Network Adapter with `Host Only Adapter` type and try connecting to it?

Comment: Yes u were correct...its working.

Comment: ok one last question. Can I connect to this VM from other machines. That is login using putty with `<host-ip>` or accessing http server with `http://<host-ip>:50070`. I know for this, we have to configure bridged network for VM. But that means I have to obtain one more IP (right?) and thats a bit tedious process in my company. Instead can I do something like forwarding requests from other machines to my host for these specific ports to my VM?

Comment: done again...cleared host-ip in port forwarding...this works like a charm

Comment: yes firewall was open. They were able to ping me. I guess issue was that the port forwarding setting in VirtualBox was `tcp|127.0.0.1|22|<vm's-ip>|22`. My friend was trying to connect with my host machines machines actual IP. But it was not working. So I changed it to `tcp|           |22|<vm's-ip>|22` (cleared host ip). And it started working. I guess with `127.0.0.1`, it will allow only my host machine to connect through putty, not others.

Comment: Ah, good point. I didn't consider that when posting my previous comment. Happy to hear it works.

Answer (score 0):

Enable nic at host for your guest. There is also where you do port forwarding if you want NAT.

Comment: Another useless answer. Your answers never seem to explain **how** to do something. Please see the other answer for a much better one.